# How to do simple error handling in flutter based on status code=200 only?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, error-handling, widget

When API hits properly it returns status code 200 in headers and data in response. When API don't hit properly due to any reason,there is no error codes or appropriate message is returning in response.Only when the API hits successfully then I am getting status code 200 in headers as usual. So, how to do error handling handling in such case to inform user if there is any failure?

Answer (score 0):

**Sample API Func**

```
 try {
     var url = Uri.parse('your_url');
    
     var response = await http.get(url);
    
     var responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Success(response: PublicUserModel.fromJson(responseJson));
     }
     return Failure(
       errorMessage: response.body,
     );
     } on HttpException {
          return Failure(errorMessage: "No Internet Connection");
     } on FormatException {
          return Failure(errorMessage: "Invalid Format");
     } on SocketException {
          return Failure(errorMessage: "No Internet Connection");
     } catch (e) {
          return Failure(errorMessage: "Invalid Error");
     }
```

**SuccessModel**

```
class Success {
  late Object response;
  Success({required this.response});
}
```

**FailureModel**

```
class Failure {
  late Object errorMessage;

  Failure({
    required this.errorMessage,
  });

  Failure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    errorMessage = json['errorMessage'][0];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['errorMessage'] = errorMessage;

    return data;
  }
}
```

**And Usage**

```
try {
      final response = await ApiCall();
      if (response is Success) {
       // Result is Success
       // do something
      } else if (response is Failure) {
       // Result is Failure
       // do something
      } 
    } catch (_) {
      // oops something went wrong
      // do something
    }
```

**And Usage - 2**

```
try {
      final response = await ApiCall();
      if (response is Success) {
       // Result is Success
       // do something
       var result = response.response;
      } else if (response is Failure) {
       // Result is Failure
       // do something
       print(response.errorMessage.toString());
      } 
    } catch (_) {
      // oops something went wrong
      // do something
    }
```

**For Example**

In my case, I follow the status in bloc and keep my work organized in this way.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rasityilmaz What is the purpose of Usage? The last one.

Comment: The purpose of that part is:
Let's say you've run an api request and you're waiting for any pattern or plain response.
Since we return two different models (success, failure) in the API function, you are checking whether things are going well according to the response you receive in this way.

Comment: So, if the response object came as Success, the request was successful and you can take action accordingly, or the request failed and the response returned as Failure, then you understand that there was an error.

For example, if the request is successful:
You can see the returned object inside the Success element,
or if Failure you can find the error message inside the failure object